# Unity Project crashes on start in iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have a bunch of apps I've made already installed on my iPad Air 1 & 2 and all of them work fine. However, I recently upgraded to iOS 9.1 and now the app crashes when my splash screen appears.

I've tried to reset my device both by doing a factory reset and by trying to reinstall 8.4 by using an ipsw file. However, apple have stopped signing anything for iOS 8 meaning I am unable to reset my version of ios to an earlier version.

In my searches, I've not been able to find any fixes for the apps I already have installed on my ipad. With my experience, when I upgrade my iOS, everything already installed should work just as they did before. However, all of my own applications now crash after being opened for 2 seconds.

Has anyone else experienced this (I've read 9.1 has broken a lot of applications) but more importantly, has anyone found a solution?

The comment below says I've not provided enough information, but I'm unsure how I can add more as my issue is not related to any of my code. I only upgraded a couple of days ago. I was happily using and testing my applications on the device just fine last week. After the upgrade, none of them are working anymore.

Comment: That's not enough information.

Comment: Not sure how I can add more information mate. Apps worked last week, upgraded to new version of ios, they no longer work. All i've done between then and now is upgrade my iOS version

Comment: Can you update Unity to the latest patch release? https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases?version=5.2

Comment: Also post the crash logs if possible.